# How to Change API url in every 10 days

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

**I want to change API url in every 10 days** for ex - url is **http://localhost3000/api/invoice/1-2-22** and starting date is 1 Feb 2022 then after 10 days change url like this **http://localhost3000/api/invoice/11-2-22**
Then date start from 11 Feb 2022 and change url after 10 day url like this **http://localhost3000/api/invoice/21-2-22**

Using JavaScript (NodeJS)

Comment: You would need to show your code.

Comment: use **URL parameter**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use URL Parameters to add the date as a URL Segment, and in the handler you can validate the date and if it's invalid you can return a 404 response.

```
app.get('/hello/:date', (req,res) = >{
    //access date using req.params.date
    //validate date here and return response accordingly 
});
```